# CakePHP 3.x: Insert values into associated table

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0

I am using the CakePHP 3.x, How to insert the values into the associated tables.

Controller:

```php
$member = TableRegistry::get('Members');
$members = $member->newEntity([
  'associated' => ['MembersRetailers']
]);
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
  $members = $member->newEntity($this->request->data(), [
     'associated' => ['MembersRetailers']
  ]);
  $member->save($members);
}
```

Model(Members):

```php
public function initialize(array $config) {
  parent::initialize($config);

  $this->table('members');
  $this->displayField('member_id');
  $this->primaryKey('member_id');

  $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

  $this->hasMany('MembersRetailers', [
    'className' => 'MembersRetailers',
    'foreignKey' => 'member_id',
  ]);
}
```

View:

```php
$session = $this->request->session();
$auth_user[] = $session->read('auth');
echo $this->Form->create($members);
// ... some input fields (not related to the question)
echo $this->Form->input('MembersRetailers.retailer_id', [
  'required' => false,
  'value'=>$auth_user[0]['retailer_id'],
  'type' => 'hidden']);
echo $this->Form->button('Create Account', ['class' => 'login-btn btn']);
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Values are inserted in `members` table but not in `members_retailer` tabel. In `members_retailer` have two fields member_id and retailer id
Value of retailer_id is not the problem But the member id of retailer table is belongsto members table!

Comment: Am I right when I assume that you did not (completely) read the Cookbooks [**Associations**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html) and [**Saving Data**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html) chapters?

Comment: @ndm No, I read that chapters

Comment: Then why don't you format the data as described there?

Comment: Sorry, I am not get you.

Comment: So that means that you did not understand what you read there? You're not the first one using this old, wrong format ( http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#associated-form-inputs ), and I'm wondering why that is. Are the docs to complicated? Do they lack specific examples?

Comment: okay thanks, i ll try above mentioned link.